# Getting This Error Visualforce Error- " System.QueryException: No such column 'name' on entity 'ContentDocument'

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have Created one vf page in which is having four Radio buttons but when i am clicking on Another RadioButton it is giving me error"Visualforce Error- " System.QueryException: No such column 'name' on entity 'ContentDocument'."

**VF Page**

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!ListWrapFile}" var="attWrap" title="All Files" id="FTable">
                    <apex:column >
                        <apex:facet name="header">
                            <apex:inputCheckbox onclick="selectAllCheckboxes(this,'inputId')"/>
                        </apex:facet> 
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!attWrap.selected}" id="inputId" onchange="selectThis(this,'{!JSENCODE(attWrap.attach.id)}_')"/>
                    </apex:column> 

               <apex:column value="{!attWrap.file.Title}">
                 <apex:facet name="header">   
                 <apex:commandLink action="{!viewSortcolumn}" reRender="panelid"   value="File Name{!IF(sortExpression=='Title',IF(sortDirection='ASC','▼','▲'),'')}" id="cmdSort">
                 <apex:param value="Title" name="column" assignTo="{!sortExpression}" ></apex:param>
               </apex:commandLink>
               </apex:facet>
               </apex:column>


                <apex:column value="{!attWrap.file.ContentSize}">
                 <apex:facet name="header">   
                 <apex:commandLink action="{!viewSortcolumn}" reRender="panelid"  value="Attachment Size{!IF(sortExpression=='ContentSize',IF(sortDirection='ASC','▼','▲'),'')}" id="cmdSort1">
                 <apex:param value="ContentSize" name="column" assignTo="{!sortExpression}" ></apex:param>
                 </apex:commandLink>
                 </apex:facet>
                 </apex:column>

                <apex:column value="{!attWrap.file.CreatedDate}">
                  <apex:facet name="header">   
                 <apex:commandLink action="{!viewSortcolumn}" reRender="panelid"  value="CreatedDate{!IF(sortExpression=='CreatedDate',IF(sortDirection='ASC','▼','▲'),'')}" id="cmdSort2">
                 <apex:param value="CreatedDate" name="column" assignTo="{!sortExpression}" ></apex:param>
                 </apex:commandLink>
                 </apex:facet>
                 </apex:column>

                    <apex:column value="{!attWrap.file.Owner.Name}" >
                        <apex:facet name="header">   
                             <apex:commandLink action="{!viewSortcolumn}" reRender="panelid"  value="Owner{!IF(sortExpression=='Owner.Name',IF(sortDirection='ASC','▼','▲'),'')}" id="cmdSort3">
                             <apex:param value="CreatedBy.Name" name="column" assignTo="{!sortExpression}" ></apex:param>
                             </apex:commandLink>
                             </apex:facet>
                             </apex:column>

                     <apex:column headerValue="(Click to view)" >
                     <apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download,attWrap.file.id)}" target="_blank">
                                 View</apex:outputLink>&nbsp;
                     <apex:commandLink value="Delete" action="{!deleteAttch}"  reRender="PGTable">
                          <apex:param id="Deleteid" name="delete" value="{!attWrap.index}" assignTo="{!opget}"/>
                      </apex:commandLink>
                       </apex:column>

                     <apex:facet name="footer">Showing Page # {!pageNumber} of {!totalPages}</apex:facet>
                </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

**Sort Expression**

```
Public String sortExpression {
        get {
            return sortExp;
        }
        set {
            //if the column is clicked on then switch between Ascending and Descending modes
            if (value == sortExp)
                sortDirection = (sortDirection == 'ASC') ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';
            else
                sortDirection = 'ASC';
            sortExp = value;
        }
    }
```

**sortDirection**

```
public String getSortDirection() {
        //if not column is selected 
        if (sortExpression == null || sortExpression == '')
            return 'ASC';
        else
            return sortDirection;
    }

    public void setSortDirection(String value) {
        sortDirection = value;
    }


public List < wrapAttachment > getListWrapFile() {
       lstWrapAttachment.clear();
       lstWrapAttachment=new List<wrapAttachment>();
       string sortFullExp = sortExpression + ' ' + sortDirection;
       String queryList = 'select Id,Title,ContentSize,CreatedDate from ContentDocument where ContentSize>=' + sSliderFieldMin * 1024 + ' AND ContentSize<=' + sSliderFieldMax * 1024; 
       system.debug('---QueryList---'+queryList);

    /*   if (fileToUser.OwnerId != NULL) {
            queryList += ' AND OwnerId =\'' + fileToUser.OwnerId + '\'';
        }*/
      queryList += ' order by ' + sortFullExp + ' Limit ' + list_size + ' offset ' + counter;
      String FinalQuery=queryList;
      system.debug('----Final Query List-------'+queryList);

      mapIdWrapAtt = new Map < string, wrapAttachment > ();
      List<ContentDocument> lstOffiles = new List<ContentDocument>();
```

> lstOffiles=Database.query(queryList); /*Error on this line */

```
        i=0;
         for (ContentDocument c: lstOffiles) {
            wrapAttachment objWrapAtt = new wrapAttachment(c,i,false);
            i++;
            lstWrapAttachment.add(objWrapAtt);
            mapIdWrapAtt.put(c.id, objWrapAtt);
        }
        if(selectedFiles!=null){
            for(String str:selectedFiles.trim().split('_')){
                //Id attId = (Id)str;
                if(str!=null && mapIdWrapAtt.containsKey(str))
                  mapIdWrapAtt.get(str).selected = true;  
            }  
        }
        return lstWrapAttachment;
    }
```

Comment: How does the variable `sortExpression` get set?

Comment: I have added sortExpression get set

Comment: In your VF page then, are you selecting/defaulting the value to be "Name"?

Comment: @Martin No i am not

Comment: What about the radio buttons and the `sortExp` variable then?

Comment: SortExp variable is Diiferent variable and Radiobuttons are with differnet exp

Comment: Sorry for all of the questions. It sounded like the problem was related to the radio buttons though. If I could see those two other things it would help me answer the question.

Comment: What does queryList look like when you execute the query?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't show the 'Another radio button' that you mentioned, but I assume it is setting 'Name' as the `sortExpression`.

That then leads to a query that tries to sort by Name, but that fails, because ContentDocument does not have a field called 'Name'. See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocument.htm

Answer (score 1):

It would help to see more of your code, but what is probably happening:

You select a radio button and the value of `sortExp` is set to "File Name".

You `get()` the value of `sortExpression`, and when doing so, it `return`s the value of `sortExp`.

This value gets put into your `queryList`, and you end up with a query string that contains:

```
... order by File Name ...
```

Which is why you see the error.